# Angular children components with attributes from parent component

Tags: angular, angular-components

I am trying to create the following component architecture.
A parent component with a large template that is a placeholder for many children components. The parent component is responsable for getting data from the server. The parent module also has a service to serve data to children components. Actual data subscription is taking a place in the child component.
Here is some relevant code:
Generic child component:

```
import { Component, OnDestroy, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataSvcService } from '../../dashboard/data-svc.service';

@Component({
 selector: 'app-generalstatistics',
 templateUrl: './generalstatistics.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./generalstatistics.component.css']
})
export class GeneralstatisticsComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy, AfterViewInit  {
@ViewChild('generalstatistics', {static: false}) span: ElementRef;
subscription;
generalStatistics = new Array({});

constructor(private dataSvc: DataSvcService) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.subscription = this.dataSvc.generalstatistics.subscribe(data => {
  this.generalStatistics = data;
 });
}
ngAfterViewInit() {
  console.log(this.span);
}
ngOnDestroy() {
  this.subscription.unsubscribe();
}
}
```

Template: generalstatistics.component.html

```
<span #generalstatistics></span>
```

Parent component (implementation template):

```
<div class="card-body pb-0">
    <app-generalstatistics></app-generalstatistics>
</div>
```

Parent component service: '../../dashboard/data-svc.service'

```
import { BehaviorSubject, Subject, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class DataSvcService {

constructor() { }
  public generalstatistics = new BehaviorSubject<Array<object>>([{}]);

public get generalStatistics(): Observable<Array<object>> {
  return this.generalstatistics.asObservable();
}
}
```

Parent component data request:

```
this.http.get<any>(`${environment.apiUrl}/api/
 home/`)
.subscribe((data: any) => {
  this.dataSvcService.generalstatistics.next(data);
});
```

My idea is that I want to have generalstatistics as a generic component. Actual data binding should take place in the parent component. I am trying adding something like this in the implementation:

```
<app-generalstatistics **#someid**></app-generalstatistics>
```

So I could identify it in the generalstatistics component code and assign the data to the span element.
But when I check for this.span.nativeElement I dont see anything coming from the actual implementation.

My question is how do I bind data to a child component in my solution? Shuold I change the whole architecture?

Thanks

Comment: Can I just confirm - you just want the data in generalStatistics of your parent, to actually be shown in your child component?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: And based on your comments to another answer, you do not know statically how many child components you'll have, is this also correct? i.e. You may have one child component, if the data requires it, or you may have several.

Comment: Well, I do know how many child components I am going to have. The reason I want to use one generic control is because they are all will be the same just showing different data.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?
In your parent component you can pass like this:

```
<app-generalstatistics [id]="someid" ></app-generalstatistics>
```

In your generalstatistics component.ts you can receive in this way:

```
@Input() id;
```

Comment: That won't even compile: 
    ERROR in src/app/views/dashboard/dashboard.component.html(7,42): Property 'someData' does not exist on type 'DashboardComponent'. because the parent component doesn't know anything about the child.

Comment: You should have the someData or someId as a class level property in your parent component.

Comment: No, that's not what I want. All I want is to have implementation to identify itself to the child component.

Comment: Can you explain in a clear way, what does 'to have implementation to identify itself to the child component' mean?. As far as I understand you just want to pass some data to the child component and the child component must behave dynamically according to the passed data, is that right?

Comment: Yes, you understand correctly. In order to assign data dynamically to the child component I need to know what is implementing it. If I have two child components in the parent I need to identify each instance to assign proper data.

Comment: Well if you have two child components in a parent template, you can just pass data to each child component.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203580/discussion-between-ramesh-and-mark).

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that your service is correctly returning your array of objects that you're looking for. All you need to do is then bind that data down to your child component.

So in your child component, it would simply have the following in the `ts` file.

```
@Input() data: any; // You can replace "any" with an interface of the expected object
```

Then in your parent html file, if you know the order in which the data is returned, you can bind the data statically, like so:

```
<app-generalstatistics
[data]="this.generalStatistics[0]"
>

<app-generalstatistics
[data]="this.generalStatistics[1]"
>
```

Or if you're unsure of how many objects will be in your array, you can simply specify:

```
<app-generalstatistics *ngFor="let gS of generalStatistics"
[data]="gS"
>
```

With any of the strategies above, you can remove your `ViewChild()`, elementRef, as you ultimately aren't using it again in your `ts` file.